# What can I say (if something) about $\mathcal A$ knowing that $\sigma (\mathcal A)=\mathcal P(\Omega)$?

Tags: probability-theory

This is exercise 2.10. from "Probability and Measure" by Patrick Billingsley.

> If $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ contains every subset of $\Omega$, then for
>   each pair of distinct points $\omega$, $\omega' \in\Omega $ we have
>   that $\exists A\in\mathcal A$ such that $I_A(\omega)\neq I_A(\omega')$.
>   Where $I_A(\omega)$ stands for the indicator function of the
>   measurable set $A$.

EDIT:
It's clear that if $\mathcal A$ is the set of all singletones (assuming $\Omega$ is countable) then $\sigma (\mathcal A)=\mathcal P (\Omega)$.
And in this case it's easy to see that the claim holds true, taking $A=\omega$.

But I cannot simply assume that $\mathcal A$ contains all singletons, since for instance $\mathcal A=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2,3\}\}$ generates the $\mathcal P(\{1,2,3\})$ but it does not contain all singletons (it contains all but one).

Is there something I can say about $\mathcal A$ knowing that it generates the Power set?

I assume that in the continuous case, the generator of the Power set must contain all singletons (and a lot of other things).

Thanks-

Comment: Define $I_A(\omega)$

Comment: @Masacroso I just added the source, it's from the Billingsley.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I added it, it's just the indicator function.

Comment: Then consider $A=\{1\}$.  $$I_{\{1\}}(1)\neq I_{\{1\}}(3)$$ Hence this is a witness to the existance

Comment: I don't know why I did't think of that @GrahamKemp.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I realised that I've committed a stupid mistake, I edited my question.

Comment: In this case you do have $\sigma(\mathcal A)=\mathcal P(\Omega)$ since it is closed under countable unions and relative complementation.  $$\{3\} = (\{1\}\cup\{2\})^{\complement_\Omega}$$  But, indeed, you cannot assume this will be the case for every measure set.  $\sigma(\{1\},\{2,3\})\neq \mathcal P(\Omega)$ for instance.

Comment: @GrahamKemp indeed in this very simplistic case things seem to work well, but I'm more concerned about the general case, actually in the case were $\Omega$ is countable I can prove that the converse assertion is true while for the continuous case it might not be true .

Comment: I would try to prove the contrapositive statement: if there are distinct $x,y\in \Omega$ such that for all $A\in \mathcal{A}$ we have that $I_A(x)=I_A(y)$ then $\sigma(\mathcal{A})\neq \wp (\Omega)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the contrapositive suppose that $w\in A \iff w'\in A$ for all $A \in \mathcal{A}$.

Look at the following $\sigma$-algebra:
$$ \mathcal{F} = \{ A \cup \{w'\} | w\in A\in \sigma(\mathcal{A}) \} \cup \{ B \cup \{w\} | w'\in B\in \sigma(\mathcal{A}) \} \cup \{ C | \{w,w'\}\cap C=\emptyset,  C  \in \sigma(\mathcal{A}) \} $$

It is easy to see that $\mathcal{F}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and that $\mathcal{A}\subset \mathcal{F}$, then $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) \subset \mathcal{F} \subsetneq \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and so $\mathcal{P}(\Omega) \neq \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

Comment: A further question, how do you conclude that $\mathcal F$ is a proper subset of $\mathcal P(\Omega)$?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}$ is constructed in a way that $w$ and $w'$ can't be separated, then the set $\{w\} \not\in \mathcal{F}$.